# Execute application/x-executable file using python code

Tags: python, subprocess

First of all, I'm new to coding and I''ve tried a lot to understand this problem but I'm stuck.
So, I have an executable (application/x-executable) file that I need to run in python code(not from command prompt). In command prompt it is working by:

```
$ ./test
> add filename.xml
```

So, what I did is I used subprocess module and I guess it is working.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('./test')
```

Now I need to pass arguments, Im trying to

```
subprocess.run('add fielname.xml', shell=True)
```

It is giving the following error

```
/bin/sh: 1: add: not found
```

Appreciate any hint or help!

Comment: I think that maybe this way you solve ```subprocess.run(["./test"],input=b"add filename.xml")```, but I'm not sure. Could try it?

Comment: Thankyouu!! that worked

Comment: `add filename.xml` isn't an argument, it's stdin. It would be an _argument_ if you ran `./test add filename.xml` at your prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in this way

```py
subprocess.run(["./test"],input=b"add filename.xml")
```

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the *Answer Well-Asked Questions* section, and therein the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before"

Comment: You are right, didn't know about that.